# css gradient line below heading

Tags: css

I have this gradient line:

```
hr {
   margin: 10px 0px;
   border: 0;
   height: 2px;
   background: #a60000;
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #B2B2B2, #a60000, #B2B2B2); 
   background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, #B2B2B2, #a60000, #B2B2B2); 
   background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, #B2B2B2, #a60000, #B2B2B2); 
   background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, #B2B2B2, #a60000, #B2B2B2); 
}
```

I want to replace the border-bottom in this css with the same gradient line:

```
h2{
    color: #000000;
    padding: 0em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 4px 0 16px 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #a60000;
 }
```

I have tried using hr:after {, but the background-image will appear at the top of the text not as a line below the text.

I want it to appear each time h2 is used.  Such as < h2 >Find Help< /h2 >.

Comment: can you post your HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `::after`?

```
h2::after{
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0px;
    content:" ";    
    width:100%;
    height:2px;
    background: #a60000;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #B2B2B2, #a60000, #B2B2B2); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, #B2B2B2, #a60000, #B2B2B2); 
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, #B2B2B2, #a60000, #B2B2B2); 
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, #B2B2B2, #a60000, #B2B2B2);
}
```

also add:

```
h2{
    position:relative;
}
```

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pE8BE/) for you

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but the line is still above    added http://jsfiddle.net/44FDh/

Comment: Look at [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pE8BE/). You forgot to add `top:100%;` in yours... also you havn't updated your `position`s